# Autocomplete doesn't work for two elements with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 `input`s with "text" type, same id and same name (like a copy-paste) and my problem is when I use autocomplete the only first one will be actived a autocomplete but second one is not. I need some help to second one be actived by use the same ID and same Name like first one.

This is my code:

```
<script> 
    $(function() {
        $('#id').autocomplete({
            source: "show.php",minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#name').val(ui.item.name);
            }
        });
</script>

<input type="text" class="code" id="id" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="รายชื่อยา" />

<input type="text" class="code" id="id" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="รายชื่อยา" />
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0z1m2sd/6/).

Comment: Elements ID **must** be unique. This is the reason why only first element is used (who will search for second element with the same ID, if standard says that element ID is unique on the page?).

Comment: You can´t have more than one element with same id, use `$('.code')` instead to select both

Comment: This question title practically answers itself

Comment: @Huangism well, I didn't think in this clue when I was editing question :)

Comment: Thank You juvian i use $('.code') that your advice it's work for me thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You should give the inputs unique ids and call the auto complete like this:

```
<script> 
    $(function() {
        $('#id, #id2').autocomplete({
            source: "show.php",minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#name').val(ui.item.name);
            }
        });
</script>

<input type="text" class="code" id="id" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="รายชื่อยา" />

<input type="text" class="code" id="id2" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="รายชื่อยา" />
```

Comment: It's worth to mention the way with class "code".

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two identical `id` . `Id` must be unique. If you want use two identical name you have to use `class` instead of `id`.